# C# Linq-to-sql server name when creating a release

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql

I'm working on C# linq-to-sql application over SQL Server express 2008 . My database is inside SQL server.

I'm using Windows Authentication to connect to sql server from my application.
The server name used in connection string is related to my pc user name, so I'm wondering if I create a release of my application and put it on client pc which have SQL Server installed with another server name, would my application work?

my connection string is

```
<add name="WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.OPTICA_MDFConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=ENG-MEDIAN-PC;Initial Catalog=OPTICA.MDF;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the app and the sql server are on the same host you can use `"Data Source=.\<instance name>"` which may be the default MSSQL.

That default would look like this:

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\MSSQL; ... "
```

For another example, our developer boxes' app.config uses this:

```
connectionString=".\DEVSQL;Initial Catalog=..."
```

Note that the "." is the host and that "DEVSQL" is the sql server instance name.